# check given date exists between two date column in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

in my database table contains 4 fields like :

```
 id  Start_date     End_date     Package
 --  ---------      ----------   --------
 1   2013-10-25     2014-04-30    pack 1
 2   2014-01-02     2014-04-30    Pack 2
 3   2014-05-01     2015-06-30    pack 3
 4   2015-07-01                   pack 4
```

i want to use date (start = 2014-01-01 and end = 2014-08-13) to check if the date is between any of the dates(Start_date, End_date) in the table. For this case, I want to get pack 1, pack 2 and pack 3. how can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure that pack 1 need to be fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [BETWEEN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) keyword of mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ( start_date BETWEEN date_from and date_to ) OR ( end_date BETWEEN date_from and date_to)
```

Comment: thank you.. it's working.. small change needed.. ie SELECT * FROM table WHERE (( start_date BETWEEN date_from and date_to ) OR ( end_date BETWEEN date_from and date_to))

Comment: @siva Your parentheses add nothing to this solution, and what if the start date is before the event end and the end date is after the event start?

Comment: but in my case i have given 2 more condition with this.. so it works bro

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '2014-01-01' <= Start_date AND '2014-08-13' >= End_date
```

Comment: Nope. But a TINY tweak will fix it.